# How to get local clipboard in jupyter running on remote server?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a `jupyter` running on a remote server and the notebook want to get data from local browser clipboard.

Here is my code with problem.

```
from IPython import get_ipython
from base64 import b64decode
import sys

def from_clipboard():
    '''
    '''
    ipy = get_ipython()
    r = ipy.run_cell_magic( "javascript", "",
        '''
        navigator.clipboard.readText().then(clipText =>{
            console.log(clipText);
            var enc = btoa(clipText);
            IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('temp_var="' + enc + '"');
            console.log(enc);
        });
        ''')
    return b64decode(sys.modules['__main__'].temp_var).decode()
print(from_clipboard())
```

When I trigger `from_clipboard` by press enter.  `IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('temp_var="' + enc + '"');` is padding and will be execute after `from_clipboard` finished.

So `sys.modules['__main__'].temp_var` is undefined at this time.

Any idea to fix that?

Comment: 'access the clipboard content' --- of client or server?

Comment: @LeiYang, of client browser.